# "undefined method `each' for "datos.txt":String"

Tags: ruby

```
class Datos
    def initialize
    end
    def meteDatos
```

sorry if the variables are in spanish, im from spain and it´s easier for me

i hope nobody cares about that...

```
        print "escribe el nombre: "
        $nombre = gets.chomp
        print "escribe el apellido: "
        $apellido = gets.chomp
        print "escribe el dia de nacimiento: "
        $dia = gets.chomp
        print "escribe el mes de nacimiento: "
        $mes = gets.chomp
        print "escribe los dos primeros digitos de el ano de nacimiento: "
        $ano1 = gets.chomp
        print "escribe los dos ultimos digitos de el ano de nacimiento: "
        $ano2 = gets.chomp
        print "escribe el color favorito: "
        $color = gets.chomp
    end 
end
datos = Datos.new()
datos.meteDatos
archivo = File.new("datos.txt","w+") 
archivo.puts $nombre
archivo.puts $apellido
archivo.puts $dia
archivo.puts $mes
archivo.puts $ano1
archivo.puts $ano2
archivo.puts $color
archivo.close
```

the problem is right here and i know it´s in the '.each' but im learning this 
 languaje and i have no clue what is going on...

```
begin
File.open ("datos.txt").each {|i| puts i}
gets()
rescue => err
    puts err.message
end
archivo.close
File.delete("datos.txt")
gets()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a whitespace between `File.open`  and `("datos.txt")`. Remove that whitespace.

`File.open ("datos.txt").each {...}` (note the whitespace) will be interpreted as `File.open(("datos.txt").each {...})`